# SCSS animation doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

It is my sccs code:

```
#logo{
  animation: zoomIn, 4s;
}

@mixin keyframes($name) {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}

// use of keyframes mixin
@include keyframes(zoomIn) {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dako</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>
<div id="top"><%= image_tag('dako.png', id:'logo') %></div>
...
```

Why it doesn't animate? I was trying add the prefix `webkit-` but it didn't help me.

Comment: This is not a Sass problem, it is a CSS problem.  Only provide the compiled CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your scss code;

1. You need to add the `-webkit` prefix in front of both `keyframes` and `animation`
2. Make sure you declare the keyframes before using them (at the moment `#logo` is looking for `animation: zoomIn` but it doesn't exist yet)
3. You shouldn't have commas in your `animation` statement

Your final code should look something like this

```
//Keyframe Mixin
@mixin keyframes($name) {
  @keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
  }
}

// Create Keyframes
@include keyframes(zoomIn) {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

//Use Animation
#logo{
  animation: zoomIn 3s;
  -webkit-animation: zoomIn 3s;
}
```